# htaccess rewrite query string to folder breaking $_GET

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /view\?i=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /view/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)$ /view?i=$1 [L]
```

This rewrites `http://domain.com/view?i=40` to `http://domain.com/view/40`.

Problem is, it seems to be breaking `$_GET['i']` (empty). This answer is from here on SO. What is causing it?

Note: I have a previous rewrite rule to remove `.php` from the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning option `MultiViews` off:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /view\?i=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /view/%1? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^view/([0-9]+)$ /view?i=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: I would also mention that you added the `QSA` flag (Query String Append), which merges your supplied query string with the original.  I feel that this is probably the actual solution instead of MultiViews.

Comment: Works now! Thank you for your help